# mark_tag_used warning with OCaml 4.02.0

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm just trying my code with OCaml 4.02 (using opam) and I get lots of warnings like this:

```
File "_tags", line 14, characters 121-134:
Warning: the tag "link(utils.o)" is not used in any flag
declaration, so it will have no effect; it may be a typo.
Otherwise use `mark_tag_used` in your myocamlbuild.ml to
disable this warning.
```

But it is defined in `myocamlbuld.ml`:

```
pdep ["link"] "link" (fun param -> [param]);
```

I can get rid of it with:

```
mark_tag_used("link(utils.o)");
```

But I need one such line for every use of the tag! Also, my code then won't build with earlier versions of OCaml. What's the general fix?

(full code is at https://github.com/0install/0install)

Comment: I've compiled a project of mine with 4.02.0 and getting the same warning over a number of tags that are in fact used. I haven't looked at it much yet, but curious if you had tracked down the cause.

Comment: No I haven't yet. I went back to 4.01.0 due to a separate problem with slow compiles (which will be fixed in 4.02.1 I hear).

Comment: It seems to be a so-far-unreported ocamlbuild bug. You should feel free to report such issues [on the bugtracker](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/).

Comment: I reported this as [PR#6893](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6893) and it should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of same warning when I did

```
dispatch @@ MyOCamlbuildBase.dispatch_combine [
  begin function
    (* ... *)
  end;
  dispatch_default
]
;;
```

instead of

```
dispatch 
begin function (* ... *)
```

in my `myocamlbuild.ml` and re-run `oasis setup`. YMMV

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not using OASIS, just plain `ocamlbuild`.